# Equation $3=x^{2}-2y^{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}_{3}$ (3-adic numbers)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm doing some examples in $p$-adic Number Theory and I got stuck in this. It's been a while since I've learned Hensel's Lemma and I'm a bit rusty on it, so I ask you to please be patient :)

The equation I want to solve is
\begin{equation}
3=x^{2}-2y^{2}
\end{equation}
over the field $\mathbb{Q}_{3}$. First of all, I know this is the norm from $\mathbb{Q}_{3}(\sqrt{2})$, and for my purposes I'm trying to avoid that. Suppose we do not know what field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_{3}$ are yet.

**Some questions**

1. I feel like such $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}_{3}$ satisfying the equation should be elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, but I forgot how to justify that. Clearing denominators only seems to work for homogenous polynomials. Right?
2. If these are indeed in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, we open up $x$ and $y$ as sequences in the inverse limit and things get reduced to the congruences
   \begin{equation}
   3\equiv x^{2}-2y^{2}\pmod {3^{n}},\qquad n\geq 1.
   \end{equation}
   Since this is two-variable, I do not remember how we apply Hensel's Lemma here. How to proceed? Will it be enough to find a solution $\pmod{3}$ as in the one variable case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in ordinary rational integers, if $u^2 - 2 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$ then both $u,v$ are divisible by $3,$ and actually $u^2 - 2 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9.$